# Setting "don't track" for the Google Ad ID in the emulator

Tags: android

I'm using the Google APIs emulator (Android 23), and I can confirm that it does have Play services - I can receive push notifications on it, as well as the Google Ad ID.

To test my app, is there any way in which I can enable the don't track option? On my Nexus, I can find this under Google Settings, but the same app isn't available on the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Marshmallow the Google settings are now a dedicated entry under the settings menu. You should have a `Google` option in the settings menu, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't bother to look there.